# Distribute function computation over several cores - R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a function like the following one:

```
FXN <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g){
value <- (a*b/c+d^e)-f+g
write.table(value, paste(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, ".txt", sep = "")}
```

(But it is a lot more computationally heavy, this just demonstrates the basic idea - does some computation on a single core; writes it to a file.)

If I want to evaluate this function in parallel on 64 cores for all combinations of

```
a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
b = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
c = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
d = c(3, 4)
e = c(5, 7, 8)
f = c(4, 5, 6)
g = c(2, 4, 6)
```

How can I do this? There are 6750 combinations of these values, so the function needs to be run 6750 times.

I am trying the following, but am not sure how foreach handles the function computation. Ideally for my actual function, it just runs the function on each core, writes the table, and moves onto the next combination which hasn't already been run.

```
library(foreach)
n_cores = 64
registerDoMC(n_cores)
foreach (a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) %dopar% {
  foreach (b = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)) %dopar%  {
    foreach (c = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)) %dopar%  {
      foreach (d = c(3, 4)) %dopar%  {
        foreach (e = c(5, 7, 8)) %dopar%  {
          foreach (f = c(4, 5, 6)) %dopar%  {
            foreach (g = c(2, 4, 6)) %dopar%  {
              FXN(
                a=a,
                b=b,
                c=c,
                d=d,
                e=e,
                f=f,
                g=g
              )
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Would this theoretically work? What other way could I distribute the 6750 combinations over 64 cores, speeding up the computations?

Thanks!

Comment: Make a table of all the input combinations, `expand.grid(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)`, then use a single `%dopar%` going down the rows of the table.

Comment: For parallelizing nested foreach, you need to use `%:%` instead of `%dopar%` (only the last one). Yet, I'll recommend parallelizing only the two (maybe three) outer loops.

Comment: @Gregor

Just to verify, you mean this, correct?
`combinations <- expand.grid(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)`

`foreach (i = 1:nrow(combinations)) %dopar% {
  a <- combinations[i, 1]
  b <- combinations[i, 2]
  c <- combinations[i, 3]
  d <- combinations[i, 4]
  e <- combinations[i, 5]
  f <- combinations[i, 6]
  g <- combinations[i, 7]
  FXN(
    a=a,
    b=b,
    c=c,
    d=d,
    e=e,
    f=f,
    g=g
  )
}`

Comment: Yes, though F. Prive as a very good point about just parallelizing some of the outer layers. Maybe use `epxand.grid(a, b, c)` and let the defg combinations happen on each processor.

Comment: @Gregor F.Prive Could you please explain why that would be beneficial? I just want to understand so I know how to use it for future applications. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's overhead in parallelization. If the tasks you do in parallel are too small, you'll spend more time on the overhead than you save.

Comment: Would this apply even if my function took over 40 minutes to compute on a single core?

Comment: Probably not, if a single iteration takes 40 minutes, then by all means parallelize each one.